# Expand and collapse icons for mat table with accordion - Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm using a generic component for displaying table with accordion. 
I somehow achieved the functionality which is working fine.
But I'm facing issue with expand and collapse icons.
when I click on a particular row I want only that row icon to be changed.
But all the icons in all rows are changed.

```
    <mat-icon *ngIf="col.columnDef == ' ' && !expanded">
      {{ expandedElement ? 'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down' }}
    </mat-icon>
```

Stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yr45pl

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please fix your line 24 in `table.component.html` to:

```
{{ expandedElement !== row ? 'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down' }}
```